# get class from generic type

Tags: java, generics

how can I call .class Or how can I get class from following generic type

```
 headerMap.put("accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
     ResponseEntity<PaginationResponse<Category>> response =
     restClient.getResource(url, headerMap, **PaginationResponse<Category>.class**);
     LOGGER.info("Method getAllCategories() - END");
```

It shows error

Comment: This is something missing from Java, called Reification.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the information is not avaiable at runtime.
But perhaps, you can use some ideas from [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

The generic type T is not kept at runtime because of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

However, if you still want to do it

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    private Class<T> type;

    public Foo(Class<T> type) { 
        this.type = type; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution for generic type class [explanation](http://gafter.blogspot.in/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)
And Spring implementation is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html) for Rest Template